# Why does this property whose value has changed in one method reset in another method?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I declare the property `int indx;` in the header file.  Then in the implementation file I have these two methods:

```
-(IBAction)nextHaiku
{
{
    if (!self.indx)
    {
        self.indx=0;
    }
    NSString *cat = self.selectedCategory;
    //For now (adjust later so that, according to UISegmentedControl, it will also show only the user's haiku or all haiku):
    cat = @"Derfner";
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"category == %@", cat];
    NSArray *filteredArray = [self.gayHaiku filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    int array_tot = [filteredArray count];
    int sortingHat;
    if (array_tot > 0)
        if (self.indx == self.theseAreDone.count)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                sortingHat = (arc4random() % array_tot);
                if (![theseAreDone containsObject:[filteredArray objectAtIndex:sortingHat]]) break;
            }
            self.haiku_text.text = [[filteredArray objectAtIndex:sortingHat] valueForKey:@"quote"];
            if (!self.theseAreDone || self.theseAreDone.count==array_tot)
            {
                self.theseAreDone = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            }
            [theseAreDone addObject:[filteredArray objectAtIndex:sortingHat]];
            self.indx = self.theseAreDone.count;
        }
        else 
        {
            self.haiku_text.text = [[self.theseAreDone objectAtIndex:indx] valueForKey:@"quote"];
            self.indx += self.indx;
        }
}
}
```

and

```
-(IBAction)previousHaiku
{
self.haiku_text.text = [[self.theseAreDone objectAtIndex:self.indx-1] valueForKey:@"quote"];
self.indx -= self.indx;
}
```

`NSLog` shows that `self.indx` increases in increments of 1 every time `newHaiku` is called.  But `NSLog` also shows that `self.indx` starts `previousHaiku` at 0, no matter what it was at the end of the last time `newHaiku` was called.

What am I missing?

Comment: `self.indx -= self.indx;` is equivalent to `self.indx = 0;`. Maybe you meant `self.indx -= 1;`?

Comment: Can happen sometimes. You look and look at a piece of code and because you are too close to it you just can't seem to see what's right in front of your face... and a second pair of eye can find it embarrassingly fast! A positive side effect of how silly you are feeling right now is that your unlikely to make the same mistake again ;-)

Answer (score 0):

What I was missing was the fact that I'm an idiot.  I was using `self.indx -= self.indx` instead of `self.indx -=1`.  Don't ask me why.  I couldn't tell you.